Dynamic user-context variable in RadioButtonBar not getting updated in parallel kernels like system variables
When I define a Dynamic user-defined context variable in a RadioButtonBar such as myContext`var2 and distribute it to the parallel kernels the kernels are not recognizing the updated value as the button is changed.  This construct works if the variable is not in a user-context.  For example if I define the button bar as:
var1 = 1;
Row[{Style["var1: ", Black, Bold],RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[var1], {1, 2, 3}]}]

Then execute:
ParallelEvaluate[ToString@var1] 

Then each time I change the button and re-execute ParallelEvaluate, var1 is equal to the currently-selected button.
However, if I assign a variable to a private context and add the context to $ContextPath as:
myContext`var2 = 1;
Context[myContext`var2]
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "myContext`"]

Then set up another button bar with this variable:
Row[{Style["var2: ", Black, Bold],RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[myContext`var2], {1, 2, 3}]}]

Distribute it to the kernels:
DistributeDefinitions[myContext`var2]

And run the kernels:
ParallelEvaluate[ToString@myContext`var2]

ParallelEvaluate will report the last value of var2 but will not report the current value of var2 as the radio button is changed unless I re-distribute the variable again before running ParallelEvaluate.
Is there a way to set this up so that I do not have to re-distribute myContext`var2 prior to running ParallelEvaluate as is done with the first example using var1?
